# Ideals in the ring of formal power series

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, formal-power-series, flatness

It is known that, if $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring, the ring of formal power series $R[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a flat $R$-algebra. This gives us a flat ring homomorphism $\phi:R \rightarrow R[[x_1,...,x_n]]$.

I would like to show that, if $a$ is an ideal of $R$, then $a^{ec} = a$. That is, if we take the extension of the ideal $a$, and then take the contraction of this extension, we get $a$ back again.

I've seen in certain solutions that $a^e = a + a \cdot (x_1,...,x_n)$, but I'm not sure how this is deduced. Does this simply follow from the definition of the extension of an ideal? Is $a^e$ an ideal of $R[[x_1,...,x_n]]$? My impression was that it must be to even make sense of its contraction $a^{ec}$. From there, how can we see what $a^{ec}$ would be? Do we have to study the homomorphism $\phi$ more?

Thanks!

Comment: To see that $a^e$, the ideal of $R[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$ generated by $a$ is $a +a (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, just look at a typical member $r = a_1r_1 + \ldots a_kr_k$ of $a^e$, where each $a_i \in a$ and each $r_i \in R[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$. We must have $r = a + r'$, where $a = a_1 + \ldots + a_k \in a$ and $r'$ has zero constant term and all other coefficients in $a$, so that $r'$ belongs to the ideal $a(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Comment: Here's a high level approach: assume that $R$ is commutative and coherent (not necessarily Noetherian), then $R[[x_1,\dots, x_n]] \cong \prod_{\Bbb N^n} R$ as an $R$-module. Over a coherent ring, any product of flat modules is flat and if at least one factor is faithfully flat, the product is faithfully flat as well. Clearly $R$ is faithfully flat, thus $R[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$ is faithfully flat over $R$. Finally, the property $a^{ec}=a$ holds for any faithfully flat ring extension.

Comment: @LukasHeger That's a great argument! How can we see the isomorphism you wrote?

Comment: @RobArthan Excellent! I suppose it's routine to check that $a + a(x_1,...,x_n)$ is indeed an ideal of $R[[x_1,...,x_n]]$. I still need help examining its contraction by $\phi$, though.

Comment: @michiganbiker898 it's quite straightforward: an element of $\prod_{\Bbb N^n}R$ is equivalently a function $f:\Bbb N^n \to R$, now just map that to the formal power series $\sum_{(m_1, \dots, m_n) \in \Bbb N^n} f(m_1, \dots, m_n)x_1^{m_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n^{m_n}$ (We should include $0$ in $\Bbb N$ here, which of course doesn't affect the argument). (Depending on how you actually define $R[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$ set-theoretically, one might even say that $R[[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and $\prod_{\Bbb N^n} R$ are even equal as sets.)

Comment: the isomorphism is quite similar to the isomorphism $R[x_1, \dots, x_n] \cong \bigoplus_{\Bbb N^n} R$